# make panorama using Homography between two images

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have to make panorama using Homography between two images. In matlab, after I get the homography matrix, how can I create a function that warp the second image and combined them together?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [very useful tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/feature-based-panoramic-image-stitching.html), with:

```
tforms(1) = projective2d(eye(3));
tforms(2) = projective2d(H);
```

where `H` is your homography matrix.